# Is there a way to modify a startup script previously registered with RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a control that must emit a javascript array of data, which is accumulated throughout the page lifecycle.

The control does not know when the data is finished being accumulated, so there is no single point where it knows when to call `RegisterStartupScript`.

How do I accomplish this then? My original plan was to call `RegisterStartupScript` each time data is added, but with the same `key`, only the first call will render anything.

So, perhaps a better question title is something like "How do I know when to call RegisterStartupScript when the script can change throughout the page lifecycle?"

Comment: Just call it from the view (err. Aspx page)?

Comment: What does the StartupScript do? If you don't know when it should be called, how should we?

Comment: It accumulates diagnostic info during page execution, to be used by a client-side viewer. The data is sent to the client via a single json object.

Comment: So, it should be executed each time before the data is sent to the client?

Comment: Yes. But my control does not know when it's finished accumulating data, so the answer is not as simple as just "call it when it's done accumulating data". The two obvious solutions are to update the startup script each time data is added (but the way RegisterStartupScript works I don't think this is possible), or register startup script as late as possible in the lifecycle, which seems precarious, and may not even be possible.

Comment: Now I can see that there is a conflict here because my control tries to live outside the confines of the page lifecycle. Maybe this can only be handled by using an `HttpHandler` or doing it from the ASPX by overriding `Render`.